# как правильно связать ID с jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть код HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="xo" id="a0" data-value="0"></div>
    <div class="xo" id="a1" data-value="1"></div>
    <div class="xo" id="a2" data-value="2"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="xo" id="a3" data-value="3"></div>
    <div class="xo" id="a4" data-value="4"></div>
    <div class="xo" id="a5" data-value="5"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="xo" id="a6" data-value="6" ></div>
    <div class="xo" id="a7" data-value="7" ></div>
    <div class="xo" id="a8" data-value="8"></div>
</div>
```

мне нужно обратится к ID a5. но число 5 задается рандомно функцией, как правильно написать например $("#???").text("текст"); или есть другой способ?

Comment: это игра крестики нолики надо чтобы ходил комп  я рандомно сделал а вот как связать с HTML ?? вот весть код https://codepen.io/xlabuchik/pen/pwZaww?editors=1111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Генерируй число в переменную, а потом конкатинируй со строкой:

```
let randItem = RandGeneratoR()// сюда суй свое значение;
idItem = '#a'+randItem;
$(idItem).doSometimes();
```

Comment: работает но както не так выдает число 7 а айди а4 или число 1 а аиди а6

Comment: извиняюсь все ОК просто я функцию рандом  еще выводил на консоль получается запускал ее 2 раза

Answer (score 2):

Как я понял вы хотите фильтровать все ID с каким-то статическим фильтром + динамическое значение, это можно сделать так:

```js
$("[id^=a]").click(function () {
  var num = this.id.slice('a'.length);
  var $elem = $('#a'+num);
  
  alert($elem.attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="xo" id="a0" data-value="0">Click</div>
    <div class="xo" id="a1" data-value="1">Click</div>
    <div class="xo" id="a2" data-value="2">Click</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="xo" id="a3" data-value="3">Click</div>
    <div class="xo" id="a4" data-value="4">Click</div>
    <div class="xo" id="a5" data-value="5">Click</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="xo" id="a6" data-value="6" >Click</div>
    <div class="xo" id="a7" data-value="7" >Click</div>
    <div class="xo" id="a8" data-value="8">Click</div>
</div>
```